# Loop with curly brackets causes wrong output

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I created 2 simple examples:

First example:

```
<?php $arr = array(1,2,3,4,5); ?>

<?php foreach ($arr as $element) ?>
<?php { ?>
    <?php echo $element; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

output:

```
5 //Is this result wrong?
```

Second example:

```
<?php $arr = array(1,2,3,4,5); ?>

<?php foreach ($arr as $element) { ?>
    <?php echo $element; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

output:

```
12345
```

What did I miss about the PHP syntax?

I know that there is an alternative foreach syntax, but in my opinion both shown examples should result in the same output. (Code tested with PHP version: 5.6.12)

**Edit:**

I know the tags are not needed in every line.
To be more precise: I want to know why the two examples give me 2 different results?

Comment: I know :D
Just wondering about the reason for this output...

Comment: just put <?php at begginning and ?> at the end.....why are you using it in every line..

Comment: Just guessing, but perhaps the ?>  in the first example is actually being taken as the statement end (loops can be used without braces). At that point, the loop has happened and `$element` is the last value. Then the braces are just take as a code block which you echo, which is 5.

Comment: I read somewhere that some framework actually adds the tags for every line.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am agree with you but you can't bind to write this in single php tag he can use <?php whereever he need thats the solution or reason

Comment: @JayBlanchard If you can figure what this framework is/was then please let us know so that we can avoid it at all costs.

Comment: I'll have to go back and look @MonkeyZeus. I basically offered the same correction on an answer sometime back and was fiercely corrected because "that is what the framework does".

Comment: @JonStirling I think you may have put your finger on it

Comment: @JayBlanchard No framework was mentioned in the question. You are safe here, this is a safe place :-) ... for now, muahaha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the output, my guess is that:

```
<?php $arr = array(1,2,3,4,5); ?>

<?php foreach ($arr as $element) ?>
<?php { ?>
    <?php echo $element; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

is being interpreted as:

```
<?php
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);

foreach ($arr as $element);
{
    echo $element;
}
?>
```

<del>Looks like a bug in the interpreter?</del> See comments by [Rizier123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3933332/rizier123):

> 1. Not a bug: stackoverflow.com/q/29284075/3933332
> 2. The brackets after the foreach()/*Do nothing here*/; is just a statement-group: php.net/manual/en/control-structures.intro.php

Anyways, the code looks atrocious with the way you have written it. Please opt for cleaner code.

---

Reading through the comments under the question I think [Jon Stirling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934966/jon-stirling) explain this symptom the best:

> Just guessing, but perhaps the ?> in the first example is actually being taken as the statement end (loops can be used without braces). At that point, the loop has happened and $element is the last value. Then the braces are just take as a code block which you echo, which is 5.

Comment: + The brackets after the `foreach()/*Do nothing here*/;` is just a statement-group: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.intro.php

Comment: I agree with the do nothing, but shouldn't $element be unkown in the curly brackets in that case?

Comment: @Thulur No, 1. The `$element` still exists from the foreach loop and holds the last value of the array. 2. The statement-group doesn't create a new variable scope, means `$element` is well known and also isn't out of scope.

Comment: @Thulur Try this `<?php $var = 'hello'; {echo $var;} ?>`

Comment: So I guess $element is declared outside the scope of the foreach loop?

Comment: @Thulur ^^ Neither the statement group nor the foreach loop creates a new variable scope. Everything in your code is in the same variable scope.

Comment: @Thulur If you're up for some "light" reading then check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works) :-)

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks, I did not know about the scopes till today o.O and now I don't like :D

Comment: @Thulur To read more about foreach see: http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php and variable scope (Which isn't the problem in your code): http://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/3933332

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `<?php` and `?>` every single line simply do:

```
<?php
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);

foreach ($arr as $element) {
echo $element;
}
?>
```

Or alternative syntax:

```
<?php
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);

foreach ($arr as $element)
{
echo $element;
}
?>
```

Or

```
<?php
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);

foreach ($arr as $element):
echo $element;
endforeach;
?>
```

When you are doing this:

```
<?php foreach ($arr as $element) ?>
<?php { ?>
    <?php echo $element; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

PHP loops nothing because it sees

```
foreach ($arr as $element)
{
}
echo $element;
```

Comment: It's true, you don't need it. But this still doesn't answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Over using `<? php>` is your problem.

You are completing the `foreach` context before outputting the result and not doing that in the second.

Look at your examples carefully and you should see what you are doing differently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you use so many php tags, but that's why it doesn't work!
try this:

```
<?php $arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);

foreach ($arr as $element)
{
    echo $element;
} ?>
```

Comment: Not what the OP asked. He asked why using the `{` in a new line caused the different behavior.